# Getting current user from Flask app and using in Dash app

Tags: python, mysql, flask, plotly-dash, flask-login

So i'm very new to Flask, Dash and Python in general

I'm currently busy with a project that requires a Dash Graph to be created from statistics within a MySQL DB. I've already build the login system etc in a normal Flask app and am currently displaying the Dash App in the Flask app using the  method so they're in separate files as well

Problem is. Each user logged in as their own table of stats that needs to be displayed on the Dash Graph (e.g if John is logged in. the graph needs to show the amount of orders John has received over a certain period)

Now my plan is to get the current_user ID from the Flask App, insert it into a variable, import it into the Dash app and then use that variable as a base for filtering through the database which i will import from MySQL but it's not working? Anyone done anything similar? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If using the `flask_login` module, it will provide what you need with the `current_user` variable. It's good to use that module in general as it's more secure and robust than most simple logins you'll build from scratch.

Comment: That was my thought as well. But how will the Dash App know which user is currently logged in if all of the functionality of that sits within the Flask App? Do i have to import the Flask App into the Dash App or just Flask Login etc?

Comment: @MusaMyeni I don't know a ton about Dash unfortunately, though I've also heard it has its own login system. Sorry I couln't be of as much help as you needed!